# top nav items not centered

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to center my links in the middle, but because i have social icons in each corner it seem to not centering in the middle. i've come to that conclusion cause the arrows have the same left or right position. How can i achieve this. the code in action can be seen here:

```
http://95.85.11.40/topnav/
```

html:

```
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="container">

        <img class="logoimage" src="css/img/messages.png">
    <img class="arrowleft" src="css/img/arrow-left.png">
    <ul>
      <li class="yellow"><a href="index.html">Firefox</a></li>
      <li class="green"><a href="index.html">Chrome</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Safari</a></li>
      <li class="red"><a href="index.html">Opera</a></li>
      <li class="purple"><a href="index.html">Internet Explorer</a></li>
    </ul>

    <img class="arrowright" src="css/img/arrow-right.png">
                <img class="twitterlink" src="css/img/twitter_32.png">
                <img class="facebooklink" src="css/img/facebook_32.png">





      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

css:

```
div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

.logoimage {
  height: 36px;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
}

.facebooklink {
  height: 36px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 4px;
right: 45px;
height: 28px;
width: 28px;
}

.twitterlink {
  height: 36px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 4px;
right: 10px;
height: 28px;
width: 28px;
}

.arrowright {
  height: 36px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 4px;
right: 400px;
height: 28px;
width: 28px;
}

.arrowleft {
  height: 36px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 4px;
left: 400px;
height: 28px;
width: 28px;
}



body {
  font: 13px/18px 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #404040;
  background: #ecedef;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 540px;
}



nav {
  height: 36px;
  background: #464b4c;
  border-top: 1px solid #353939;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2e3131;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #464b4c, #3f4344);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #464b4c, #3f4344);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #464b4c, #3f4344);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #464b4c, #3f4344);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
}
nav a {
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: 0.1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-property: background-color, line-height;
  -moz-transition-property: background-color, line-height;
  -o-transition-property: background-color, line-height;
  transition-property: background-color, line-height;
}
nav ul {
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid #353939;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-right: 1px solid #4d5354;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
}
nav li {
  float: left;
}
 nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px #2e3131;
  border-left: 1px solid #4d5354;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
  border-right: 1px solid #353939;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav a:hover {
  background: #4d5354;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `position: absolute` from the arrows and change their style like so

```
.arrowleft {
    float: left;
    height: 28px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    width: 28px;
}

...

.arrowright {
    float: right;
    height: 28px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    width: 28px;
}
```

and finally remove `float:left` from `ul`

---

Final result (on `Firefox 29`)

[image]

Comment: have you removed the float from `ul` as suggested above?

Comment: You may possibly be on an outdated browser, try updating or using Chrome.

Comment: The problem is your width.  Your div.container is not wide enough to fit all over the elements.
First, set the .container to overflow hidden.
And make sure it is wide enough to fit all of your elements.

Along with doing what Fabrizio has asked.

Comment: okay i've changed it o 600px but then the content is not centered in the contain div. how can this be achieved?

Comment: try to add just a few pixels... like 541/542px instead of 540. Anyway it's hard to tell if we don't know which browser are you using

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can structure the menu like so:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<img class="arrowleft" src="css/img/arrow-left.png">
<ul>
  <li class="yellow"><a href="index.html">Firefox</a></li>
  <li class="green"><a href="index.html">Chrome</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Safari</a></li>
  <li class="red"><a href="index.html">Opera</a></li>
  <li class="purple"><a href="index.html">Internet Explorer</a></li>
</ul>
<img class="arrowright" src="css/img/arrow-right.png">
</div>
```

and apply this css:

```
#wrapper {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0px;
}
.arrowleft, .arrowright, ul, li {
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}
```

Remember to remove your `floats` from elements within the `#wrapper` so that they center properly. Also remember to specify your correct font sizes on a new `li` declaration.

`zoom:` and `*display:inline` are fixes for IE in that they solve a bug with inline blocks not being applied to elements without inline and hasLayout properties. `font-size:0` fixes the space that is applied between the elements since they are inline items on new lines.